# flutter webView script non-English error : Invalid argument (string): Contains invalid characters

Tags: flutter, webview

```
WebView(
          initialUrl: _customScriptHTML(),
.
.
.
```

```
  String _customScriptHTML() {
    String iosSetting = '';

    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      iosSetting = 'min-width:${width}px;min-height:${height}px;';
    }

    return Uri.dataFromString('''
<html>
<header>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes\'>
</header>
<body style="padding:0; margin:0;">
    <div id='map' style="width:100%;height:100%;$iosSetting"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='https://dapi.kakao.com/v2/maps/sdk.js?autoload=true&appkey=$kakaoMapKey'></script>
    <script>
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
There is an error if there is a language other than English!    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    </script>
</body>
</html>
    ''', mimeType: 'text/html').toString();
  }
```

### **An error occurs when writing a non-English language in the script!
How can you solve it?**

[√] Flutter (Channel unknown, 2.2.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.1052], locale ko-KR)
• Flutter version 2.2.0 at C:\Users\pc\fvm\versions\2.2.0
• Framework revision b22742018b (6 weeks ago), 2021-05-14 19:12:57 -0700
• Engine revision a9d88a4d18
• Dart version 2.13.0

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
• Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
• Java binary at: D:\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
• Android Studio at D:\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin version 47.1.2
• Dart plugin version 193.7361
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add following;

```
encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8')
```

Comment: Where should I add it?   
Webview widget does not have property 'encoding'.

Comment: I found it!
Thank you so much.

Comment: Where is it? @RaD